# Locus of a point?

Tags: geometry

Find the locus of a point such that the sum of the squares of its distances to:

a)the sides of a given square is constant

b)the vertices of a given square is constant

Let $P(x,y)$ be any point in the locus, I drew a square (1 unit per side) so that it has one vertex in $(0,0)$

I got:

$x^2+y^2+x^2+(y-1)^2+(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(x-1)^2+y^2=K$ (for all the vertex)

but I cant get to the result, any **Hints**?

Comment: Are you adding (b) the distance to the vertex of a square to (a) the sum of distances to the four sides, or are these two separate problems.

Comment: It's just one locus(a circle I think) , but it has to satisfy both a and b

Comment: @rulo1992 thanks for deleting the old duplicate, but bear in mind for the future that it is frowned upon to repeat questions and delete the down voted copies

Comment: I don't really know where to "put" P, can P be located at the origin?

Comment: Hint: You very easily see that condition b is a consequence of condition a...

Comment: @Martigan I can't really visualize the locus in my mind, can you help me?

Comment: You seem to interpret (b) as requiring the sum (of squared distances) to all four vertices of the square, but your wording has "vertex" (singular) in that part (b).  Which is correct?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant vertices(as in plural), english is not my first language, sorry for that.

Comment: @rulo1992 You don't have to bother with condition b. Just study condition a... It is only to simplify the problem, not to solve it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a square of length 1.

With condition a you have:

$x²+y²+(x-1)²+(y-1)²=A$, with $A$ being the constant.

$x²+y²+(x-1)²+(y-1)²=2(x-\frac{1}{2})²+2(y-\frac{1}{2})²+1$

So you have then $(x-\frac{1}{2})²+(y-\frac{1}{2})²=\frac{A-1}{2}$

It is a circle of center $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ and of radius $\sqrt{\frac{A-1}{2}}$, for $\frac{A-1}{2}\geq 0$

Comment: (x−1)^2+(x+1)^2+(y−1)^2+(y+1)^2=2x^2+2y^2+4=C.
(x−1)^2+(y−1)^2+(x+1)^2+(y−1)^2+(x−1)^2+(y+1)^2+(x+1)^2+(y+1)^2=4x^2+4y^2+8=C   I got this, and it's different from your answer. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you putting $(x+1)²$?. The square I took is of length 1 and with a lower left vertex in $(0,0)$. Moreover, the constant you are referring to cannot be the same... by construction. If you develop b, you will find that b is twice a...

Comment: ok thanks now I got it right I was using a square with center in the origin but it was more difficult